# How to add chips/tags to a node's properties in Node-RED

Tags: javascript, html, node-red

I'm creating a Discord node in Node-RED, and want to give the node options as to which Discord events it will subscribe to. I'm currently attempting to use Chips from the MaterializeCSS library (https://materializecss.com/chips.html).

Following the examples on the Materialize page, here's my current property type:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    RED.nodes.registerType('discordEvents', {
        category: 'config',
        defaults: {
            name: {value:"", required: true},
            events: {value:"", required: true},
        },
        exportable: false,
        label: function() {
            return this.name;
        }
    });
</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<script type="application/javascript">
    $('.chips-autocomplete').chips({
        autocompleteOptions: {
            data: {
                'message':null,
                'ready':null
            },
            limit: Infinity,
            minLength: 1
        }
    });
</script>
<script type="text/x-red" data-template-name="discordEvents">
    <div class="form-row">
        <label for="node-config-input-name"><i class="icon-tag"></i> Name</label>
        <input type="text" id="node-config-input-name">
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
        <label for="node-config-input-events"><i class="icon-tag"></i> Events</label>
        <div class="chips chips-autocomplete" id="node-config-input-events></div>
    </div>
</script>
```

The problem is when I load the library into the script, the Node-RED editor disappears, and if I check the console, I see an error "[node-red/discordEvents] TypeError: $(...).chips is not a function"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not add script tags like that in the node's html file. You need to dynamically load them as part of the node's `oneditprepare` function.

You can look at the [node-red-node-geofence](https://github.com/hardillb/node-red-node-geofence) node for an example.

This uses the jquery `$.getScript()` function to load the script.

Comment: That makes a lot more sense than what I was doing haha. I moved things around and no longer get errors like that, but now whenever I open the node to edit the events, the .css loads and turns my node red editor blank. There are no errors in the console